# How to check for null value for a double which is taken from a database

Tags: java, mysql, null, double

I am extracting values from a database. I am extracting a double value from a database using

```
ResultSet rs = ....;
while(...){
  rs.getDouble("num");
}
```

How do I check if the value of rs.getDouble("num") is a null. Since the value is stored as a (MySQL) double and I want to store it in my JVM as a double, I can't simply use !=null.

What is the easiest way. Would converting the value to a Double() and then doing .equals(null) be the easiest/best (in your opinion) way?

Comment: It would probably help if you actually assigned that value to a variable. Unless all you care about is null versus not-null.

Answer (score 10):

Test rs.wasNull() after the rs.getDouble().

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! You have saved me a week time of work!

Answer (score 0):

So the javadoc says it returns 0 if it was null. So what you need to do is call wasNull() (on the result set) if the value was 0; then you'll know if it was really 0 or null.